# What is the difference between using a python script running on server and a stored procedure?

Tags: python, database, performance, postgresql, plpgsql

my teammate and i wrote a Python script running on the same server where the database is. Now we want to know if the performance changes when we write the same code as a stored procedure in our postgres database. What is the difference or its the same??

Thanks.

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing what your Python script does. Can you share the script or tell us what does it do?

Comment: it fetches thousand of records, put them in memory using python diccionaries, make some math for each one and then store them back on the database on another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be differences - PostgreSQL stored procedures (functions) uses inprocess execution, so there are no any interprocess communication - so if you process more data, then stored procedures (in same language) can be faster than server side application. But speedup depends on size of processed data.

Comment: ok, but in our script we only communicate with the database at the beginning to fetch data and at the end to commit data so there is not much interprocess communication. Is there any other difference??.. Are the loops handled better on a stored procedure maybe??

Comment: what is FETCH? - a lot of communication between db and client invisible for developer.

Comment: Mm didnt know that, im a newbie on this. So if i make something like: dictionary = cursor.fetch() ... am i making lot of communication?? thats new. Can you please give me a link where i can get a deeper understanding about this?? Thank you!

Comment: yes, there is not too much handshake call - but you have to move all content from server to client, what means a copy of memory between processes as minimum.

Comment: Mmm but with stored procedure i have to move all content from server to client also, right? i think that the real difference are the handshakes.. am i right? thanks.

Comment: in stored procedure all content is in one process (in PostgreSQL). Real differences depends on used HW parameters. handshake is probably most important. You can do a experiment and you will see.

Comment: Ok, really interesting thank you so much Pavel for your time.. we will go definitely with stored procedures :)